# TypeError: Cannot read property 'room' of undefined from Javascript Mastery's Video

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am getting this error message, I tried everything, but I cannot understand the problem.
This doubt is from Javascript Mastery's chat application video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwFA3YMfkoc&list=PLnVfUXqrBawfHoUBpnghPZed-TteNYBRn&index=4

Error Message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'room')
at Socket. (C:\Users\Jatan\chat-app\server\index.js:43:20)
at Socket.emit (node:events:520:28)
at Socket.emitUntyped (C:\Users\Jatan\chat-app\server\node_modules\socket.io\dist\typed-events.js:69:22)
at C:\Users\Jatan\chat-app\server\node_modules\socket.io\dist\socket.js:465:39
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Index.js :

```
 socket.on('sendMessage', (message , callback) => {
        const user = getUser(socket.id)

        io.to(user.room).emit('message', {user:user.name, text: message})

        callback();
    })
```

Edit:

console.log(user) result:

```
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Server has started on port 5001
undefined
C:\Users\Jatan\chat-app\server\index.js:47
        io.to(user.room).emit('message', {user:user.name, text: message})
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'room')
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jatan\chat-app\server\index.js:47:20)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at Socket.emitUntyped (C:\Users\Jatan\chat-app\server\node_modules\socket.io\dist\typed-events.js:69:22)
    at C:\Users\Jatan\chat-app\server\node_modules\socket.io\dist\socket.js:465:39
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

result after console.log(socket.id):

```
Server has started on port 5001
3EQA0pQ5RuZenc8nAAAH
C:\Users\Jatan\chat-app\server\index.js:46
        io.to(user.room).emit('message', {user:user.name, text: message})
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'room')
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jatan\chat-app\server\index.js:46:20)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at Socket.emitUntyped (C:\Users\Jatan\chat-app\server\node_modules\socket.io\dist\typed-events.js:69:22)
    at C:\Users\Jatan\chat-app\server\node_modules\socket.io\dist\socket.js:465:39
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Can you share console.log(user) result before io.to part ? Your user probably undefined

Comment: it means that `user` is undefined. So either `socket.id` is incorrect or `getUser` does not return the correct value.

Comment: @Evren I have edited the post, you can see the console.log(user) result.

Comment: @Ben So what changes do I need to make?

Comment: As you see in console after your server starts it prints undefined. You do not have defined data for user. You should some defined value from this function getUser(socket.id)

Comment: @Evren can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: @Ben I have edited the post , you can see the result after I console logged socket.id.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution.

Updated code:

```
const users = [];

const addUser = ({id,name,room}) => {
    //name = name.trim().toLowerCase();
    //room = room.trim().toLowerCase();

    const existingUser = users.find((user)=> user.name === name && user.room === room)

    if (existingUser) {
        return {error: 'Username is taken'}
    }

    const user = {id,name,room};

    users.push(user);

    return {user}
}

const removeUser = (id) => {
    const index = users.findIndex((user) => user.id === id)

    if (index !== -1){
        return users.splice(index, 1)[0]
    }
}

const getUser = (id) => {
    const user = users.find((user) => user.id === id)
    return user
}

const getUsersInRoom = (room) => {users.filter((user) => user.room === room)}

module.exports = { addUser, removeUser, getUser, getUsersInRoom}
```

Thanks everyone who tried to solve my problem.